# Loop through three List(Of T) by index

Tags: c#

I have three list(Of T) lists:ThkList, EngList and RefList.

Each list contains an object I want to persist to DB, but I need to process each list object in index order for each list.

Once I save the 1st ThkList object I want to remove it from the list, then process the 1st EngList object and then remove it from the list and finally process the RefList object and remove it. Finally move on to the next set of indexes per list.

How can I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting them to arrays and then using a regular for loop with an index variable.  Inside the for loop, do your database operation with elements from each of the list, all referenced by the same index variable.  Unless you really need speed, this should work well.  Also, if your lists aren't all the same length you'll need to do some bounds checking.

I'm assuming you're using VB.

```
For counter as Integer = 0 to ThkList.Count - 1

DoDBOperation(ThkListAsArray(counter))
ThkListAsArray.RemoveAt(0)

DoDBOperation(EngListAsArray(counter))
EngListAsArray.RemoveAt(0)

DoDBOperation(RefListAsArray(counter))
RefListAsArray.RemoveAt(0)

End For
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the approach!

Comment: No problem! I forgot to include the declaration of the AsArray variables, but you just set one to .ToArray() for each list object.